# Create the login and validate email address

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a login page in JavaScript and here is the wrong code. All I want is that when I enter a wrong email address, it should show an alert when I left it blank then it show an alert.

```js
function check(form) {
  if (form.email.value == "id@gmail.com") {
    alert("correct username")
  } else if (form.email.value == "") {
    alert("blank username")
       }

    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
      alert('Please provide a valid email address');
      email.focus;
      return false;
    }
  } else if (form.pswrd.value == "123") {
    alert("correct details")
  } else if (form.pswrd.value == "") {
    alert("blank password")
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Login </h1>
<form name="login">
  Username <input type="text" name="email"/>
  Password <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
  <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not a valid script! `<script>` is HTML, while the contents are JavaScript. Well, try to understand. `:)` And also, `then` ≠ `than`!!!

Comment: It doesnt look like you are closing this statement `else if (form.email.value == "") {` and therefore never goes on to test via regex on a valid email address. At the moment it will always apply the regex test to an email address that is blank.

Answer (score 1):

**Mistakes:**

1. You are not supposed to use `<script>` tags inside JavaScript. They are invalid.
2. You haven't given an `id="email"` to the `input`. So that doesn't work.
3. Add an `else` part for email validation.
4. Separate your `password` check from the `email` check `if...else` block.

**Working Snippet**

```js
function check(form) {
  if (form.email.value == "id@gmail.com") {
    alert("correct username")
  } else if (form.email.value == "") {
    alert("blank username")
  } else if (form.email.value != "") {
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
      alert('Please provide a valid email address');
      email.focus;
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (form.pswrd.value == "123") {
    alert("correct details")
  } else if (form.pswrd.value == "") {
    alert("blank password")
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Login </h1>
<form name="login">
  Username <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  Password <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login" />
  <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You will still need to fix the `else if (form.email.value == "") {` condition as it never closes and therefore will never pass a potentially valid email address to be tested against by the regex filter.

Comment: @UsainBloot Even before you comment, I have fixed it buddy.

Comment: when i enter wrong email then it not showing alert @praveenkumar